# How to create nested loops under unpredictable results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a web crawler application. It will list all links of a given domain as a part of categorized site map. I'm using `Nokogiri` gem for parsing and searching the HTML. This code works for a single page:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("url"))
links = doc.css("a")

unless links.blank?
    links.each do |t|
        if t["href"].first == "/"
            // link stuff
        end
    end
end
```

At the commented line, I can do another `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(t_URL))` and receive the second set of links so on and so forth. But what about 3rd, 4th or 5th steps?

How will I crawl all other pages of the entire site and other pages having link at the previous pages? The number of links for per page is not predictable, so I can't use `each` or `times`. How can I keep visiting all pages and other nested pages and track the links of all of them?

Comment: One way is to make a method of the code you are showing and call it again (recursively) when you encounter an `href` in a link and you extract the HTTP address from it.

Comment: I would use a hash and store the routes as absolute paths from root. Then lookup the entry in the hash and if it doesn't exist add it. If you want to track depth you can nest hashes. You could also have an array and check if the path is in the array

Comment: Guys, some sample code would be very appreciated :\ I feel lost about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is keep track of the absolute URLs in a hash. The value of the hash could be a count or you may want to keep track of when you last scraped each page with a timestamp. Note when you scrape, you should get just the `href`s:

```
to_visit = {"url" => Time.now}

while !to_visit.empty? do

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(to_visit.shift.first))

  doc.css("a[href]").each do |link|
    url = make_absolute(link)
    to_visit[url] = Time.now #add this page to the to_visit 'list'
  end

end
```

Where you'll need to define `make_absolute` which should create a full URL complete with protocol, host, port, and path.

Comment: Hi Mark, pardon me but I didn't understand if this answer is related to my question :\ As I said above, I can get a list of links in a given page, but I don't know how to loop over pages. Let's say 1st pages links are captured. How will I get other links of other pages which are navigated to another?

Comment: That was the purpose of the `to_visit` hash. It could have been a `Set` because it basically just needs to be a unique list of pages you need to visit. I've added a loop so you can see how you might iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, `each` or `times` are to be used when the iterator is fixed in advance. When you do not have a fixed iterator, you need to use loops like `loop`, `while`, `until`, and break from it when all links have been found.